# Soundplayer PlaySync() works in console app but other play methods don't

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, console-application

I have used Winforms to create an app that displays buttons and plays a given note when you click on each (a virtual guitar). I am now trying to create the same thing as a console app, for the sake of writing my own code as a portfolio piece rather than relying on the UI.

I have the code below which I have successfully run in eventhandlers in a Winforms application:

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
        "WindowsFormsApp1.04-Low_G.wav"));
    sp.Play();
```

I understand that writing such things through a console app may be awkward, and if I was having no luck with it I would understand. However, I have managed to recreate this in the console app, but using the PlaySync() method only. In Winforms I can use Play(), PlaySync() or PlayLooping().

Any idea why only one of these three methods would work in the console app?

Comment: The most obvious reason is that the program terminates too soon.  Add `Console.ReadLine();` to the bottom of Main() and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad that Play() is actually working. I've found Thread.Sleep handy for this as well.